# How to properly use a list in a function to that would work on all inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a small program that will print out the next fibonacci numbers.

For example, if I use `[0,1,1]`, the fibonacci numbers would be `[1,1,2]`. If I try `[5,8,21]`, it would print `[8,13,34]`

I can't figure out how to create the loop.

```py
def numberz(lst):
    a = lst*(1+sqrt(5))/2.0
    return [round(a) for number in lst]

test=[5,8,11]
print(numberz(test))
```

It gives me a:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.

Comment: `[5, 8, 21]` can't be part of a Fibonacci sequence, as 21 isn't equal to 5 + 8

Comment: I am sorry for not wording my question accurately. The 5,8,21 is supposed to return the next fibonnaci number after 5 (8), the next one after 8 (13)and the next one after 21(34), thus 8, 13, 34.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to multiply the list by a number like here `lst*(1+sqrt(5))/2.0` Also, having said that, that multiplication doesn't make sense in the context of fibonacci numbers at all to begin with. Are you familiar with how to get the next element in a fibonacci sequence?

Comment: The ratio of any two consecutive entries in the Fibonacci sequence is about x=(1+sqrt5)/2. And now I realize my mistake as I am trying to input 3 numbers.

Comment: You can calculate the Fibonacci numbers directly: Fn = 1/sqrt(5) *  ( (1+sqrt(5))/2.0)**n - (1-sqrt(5))/2.0)**n) - But the formula used in the code forgets about the second part...

Comment: I just tested it with 10 inputs and all of them are correct so the formula works. If I try test=[89, 233, 377, 987] I get all the appropriate values = [144, 377, 610, 1597]. I am just trying to get the next fibonacci entry.

Comment: It works a bit by chance, because the second term is always small enough so that the rounding gives you the right value....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't multiply the *list* `lst` by the floating-point number `(1+sqrt(5))/2.0`. You'll have to multiply each element individually in the list comprehension:

```
def numberz(lst):
    golden_ratio = (1+sqrt(5))/2.0
    return [round(number * golden_ratio) for number in lst]
```

But that formula doesn't yield Fibonacci numbers, so the math is incorrect. The thing about the Golden ratio is that the quotients of neighbour Fibonacci numbers approach the Golden ratio:

```
Fib Quotients Golden ratio approximation
1 
1   1/1       1
2   2/1       2
3   3/2       1.5
5   5/3       1.(6)
8   8/5       1.6
13  13/8      1.625
...
144
233 233/144   1.618055556
377 377/233   1.618025751
...
```

And the approximation gets closer and closer, but it doesn't mean you can generate Fibonacci numbers so simply

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you. Need to work on understanding list comprehensions.

Anyway as you said the math is incorrect. The formula will show the next two fibonacci entries. It fails as I try to find 3 entries. EDIT: Nope, the formula is correct.

Comment: @DarknessPlusPlus, it gives incorrect results, so it can't be correct. [Here's the correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_sequence)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
import math

def numberz(lst):
    return [round(number*(1+math.sqrt(5))/2.0) for number in lst]

test=[5,8,21]
print(numberz(test))
```